# Evaluate user expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression

I am developing a web application where there is a textbox. User enters a condition to show specific color for a "string". This string holds some integer value.

User specifies condition for the string value like this,

```
>30:"Red"
<20:"Green"
:"Yellow:
```

This is one condition. It is something like if,elseif,else condition. User can specify only if,else like condition like this

```
>60:"Blue"
:"White"
```

(Which means if the string value greater than 60 then get "Blue" as color for the string else "White" is the color for the string)

I have to evaluate color for the string based on the above condition entered in the textbox for each string. There are thousands of strings with values and user will enter such expression for each string.

what is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: i have created assemblies for each expression and loaded them on runtime to evaluate expression but because there are so many asemblies  and loading them at runtime to evaluate expression is leading to memory issue.

Comment: you need to parse this string first ,tokenize it , and build condition on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = getTextBoxInput() // get input from text box
if(input.contains("<") || input.contains("<"))
{
   if(input.contains("<"))
   {
      int index = input.indexOf("<");
      String conditionString = input.substring(index+1,input.length());
      // condition number is the number being compared
      int conditionNumber = conditionString.split(":")[0];
      // if condition is true then get the corresponding colour
      if(number < conditionNumber){setColor(conditionString.split(":")[1])}
      // check if it an if else condition and do the following
      else if(input.length()>1){ setColor(conditionString.split(":")[2])}
   }
}
```

This is the basic pseudo code. You can define constants for "<" and ">" . Also you may need to do some exception handling incase of incorrect input.

Answer (score 0):

please see [Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm , you need to have something similar